# MySQL & Java - Get id of the last inserted value (JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)

Hi, I'm using JDBC to connect on database through out Java.

Now, I do some insert query, and I need to get the id of last inserted value (so, after a `stmt.executeUpdate`).

I don't need something like `SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`, because I may have concurrency problems.

I Just need to retrieve the id associated to the last insertion (about my instance of the Statement).

I tried this, but seems it doesn't work on JDBC :

```
public Integer insertQueryGetId(String query) {
    Integer numero=0;
    Integer risultato=-1;
    try {
        Statement stmt = db.createStatement();
        numero = stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (rs.next()){
            risultato=rs.getInt(1);
        }
        rs.close();

        stmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        errore = e.getMessage();
        risultato=-1;
    }
  return risultato;
}
```

In fact, every time `risultato = -1`, and I get `java.sql.SQLException: Generated keys not requested. You need to specify Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to Statement.executeUpdate() or Connection.prepareStatement().`

How can I fix this problem? Thanks Stackoverflow People :)

Comment: See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224228/preparedstatement-with-statement-return-generated-keys

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Wouldn't you just change:

```
numero = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

to:

```
numero = stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Take a look at the documentation for the JDBC [`Statement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) interface.

**Update**: Apparently there is a lot of confusion about this answer, but my guess is that the people that are confused are not reading it in the context of the question that was asked. If you take the code that the OP provided in his question and replace the single line (line 6) that I am suggesting, everything will work. The `numero` variable is completely irrelevant and its value is never read after it is set.

Comment: You Rock!!! Heheh, im not so able to read this warning message :)

Comment: +1 for `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`

Comment: yeah, this does not really work. Try inserting a couple of records, delete all of them (NOT TRUNCATE) and see if the correct ID is retreived ;)

Comment: The referenced manual page states that the returned value is _the number of records changed_ and not the _index value(s)_ (it can't do that with a single integer, there might be several).  So this won't work! See Buhake Sindi's answer for a way which should actually work.

Comment: @wu-lee The return value is irrelevant (in OP's question, `numero` is not used). You'll notice that he iterates over the `ResultSet` returned by `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`. Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: That is just wrong... Method executeUpdate returns:
either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing.
You have to create resultset and get the last ID like this:                          rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();
   
            if(rs.next())
            {
                insertId = rs.getInt(1);
            }

Comment: I see now, ... Then the varible "numero" is irrelevant as you said.

Comment: a hidden gem :)

Answer (score 146):

Alternatively you can do:

```
Statement stmt = db.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
numero = stmt.executeUpdate();

ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()){
    risultato=rs.getString(1);
}
```

But use Sean Bright's answer instead for your scenario.

Comment: If your table key has any partitions this code will be error. My suggestion use risultato=rs.getString(1);