# Get last inserted auto increment id in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to get the mysql command like mysql_insert_id(); which retrieve the last inserted row's auto_increment id. What can I do to get it in Java?

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select last_insert_id() from schedule");
lastid = rs.getString("last_insert_id()");
```

my lastid was declared as INT. I dono what to use in rs.get and also the parameter..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using an alias

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select last_insert_id() as last_id from schedule");
lastid = rs.getString("last_id");
```

Comment: Why do you add FROM statement? It's harmful because if your table contains 2 rows you'll get 2 rows as a result. "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();" is enough.

Comment: And instead of rs.getString("last_id") you can call rs.getString(1).

Answer (score 28):

Using JDBC, you can use **[Connection.PreparedStatement(query, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)** method.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(Query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);  
pstmt.executeUpdate();  
ResultSet keys = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();    
keys.next();  
key = keys.getInt(1);
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it always return 1. I somehow thought this is for checking did it insert any query into database?

Comment: @Maki92 i dont really understand your comment. this piece of code just returns the last auto-increment_id from your table . BTW, ASAIK this is the standard way of doing using JDBC.

Comment: I had seen people using it, but they faced same problem which same as mine. The code always return 1 from table.

Comment: @Maki92 i am most certainly sure that then its a problem in their code. i my self use it and never really faced such problems.. :)

Comment: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id.html

Comment: I have the exact problem. That always returns 1 not matter what the real index is.

Answer (score 7):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246646/mysql-java-get-id-of-the-last-inserted-value-jdbc) post for answer & explanation

```
Statement stmt = db.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
numero = stmt.executeUpdate();

ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()){
    risultato=rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM schedule
```

If id your column has a different name than `id`, you need to replace it accordingly in the above query.

You can use it like:

```
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM schedule");
int lastid = rs.getInt("id");
```

Comment: I din't think of it.. haha.. Last time do PHP with using mysql_insert_id();, suddenly switched to java so I only focus with it. Thanks for suggestion. :)

Comment: `int lastid = rs.getInt("id");` will throw an error since `id` doesn't exist. you should add an alias first on your select statement. `rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(id) id FROM schedule");`

Comment: @JW. Thank's for the hint. Updated my answer.

Comment: You should not rely on max(id), because another thread can insert a new row between your insert and select statements and you'll get wrong id.

Comment: Yep, same applies to mysql_inserted_id and last_inserted_id functions, which may also cause issues due to race conditions on other threads, specially considering that usually web applications share the same database user.

Comment: @jlordo, what if my last inserted Id has more than 1 row ? can i still use the same sql as you mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to get last auto_incremented ID of last inserted row.

```
SELECT (max(auto_incr_id)) from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

`SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT last_insert_id()");

while(rs.next()){
    System.out.println("id = " + rs.getLong(1));

}
```