# mysql, java - Get last inserted auto increment id from one table and insert it again on another table

Tags: java, mysql

its duplicate question with [Get last inserted auto increment id in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170656/get-last-inserted-auto-increment-id-in-mysql)

I'm creating a group it insert on `M_GROUPS`.

`M_GROUPS` table:

```
GROUP_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
GROUP_CREATOR_ID INT
```

which from session.

I need to take `GROUP_ID` and `GROUP_CREATOR_ID` and insert it on
`M_GROUP_MEMBERS` table as

```
GROUP_ID INT,
MEMBER_ID INT.
```

My problem is I can't take auto increment value `GROUP_ID` from `M_GROUPS`

```
public void groupCreation(String groupname, int grouptype, int creator_id) {

    DatabaseService oDatabaseService = new DatabaseService();
    Connection connection = oDatabaseService.connect();
    try {
        Statement stmt = null;
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String sql;

        sql = "INSERT INTO M_GROUPS( GROUP_NAME, GROUP_CREATOR_ID,
                                     GROUP_TYPE, CREATION_TIME)"
            + " VALUES ('"
            + groupname
            + "','"
            + creator_id
            + "','"
            + grouptype + "',NOW())";

        //stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`getGeneratedKeys()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) method from your `Statement` object to identify the new auto generated values. Iterate the returned `ResultSet` object to get the newly generated key values in the order of batch statements.

Change:

```
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

To:

```
int rowsAffected = 
  stmt.executeUpdate( sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS );  
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();  

//******************************************************  
// in case of batch insert, you can check how many are inserted
rs.last();  
int rows = rs.getRow();  
System.out.println( "Generated keys count: " + rows );  
//******************************************************/  

int currentRow = 1;  
rs.beforeFirst();  
while( rs.next() ) {  
    System.out.println( /**/( currentRow++ ) + " = " + /**/rs.getInt( 1 ) );  
} // while rs
```

Once you have this auto generated key value in a variable, you can use it with other SQL statements, to store in other tables.

***Note***: Call to `getGeneratedKeys()` may throw [`java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLFeatureNotSupportedException.html), if the JDBC driver, that you are using, does not support this method.

Comment: Not working means what? `rs.getInt( 1 )` gives you the value of just generated auto incremented primary key value from your insert statement.

Comment: it give java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)

Comment: It must be on your any other statement, like `insert`. Check if you are passing same number of values for columns you want to insert into. And show me the statement too.

Comment: sir @Ravinder, i do this could u please check the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423194/java-mysql-why-not-working-get-last-inserted-id-from-one-table-and-insert-it-a