# java,mysql - why not working get last inserted id from one table and insert it again on another table?

Tags: java, mysql

Its duplicate Question. I put again coz it gives me error

I'm creating a group it insert on M_GROUPS.

I need to take     GROUP_ID and     GROUP_CREATOR_ID and insert it on
    M_GROUP_MEMBERS table as GROUP_ID INT, MEMBER_ID INT.

my code is

```
public void groupCreation(String groupname, int grouptype, int creator_id) {

    DatabaseService oDatabaseService = new DatabaseService();
    Connection connection = oDatabaseService.connect();
    try {
        Statement stmt,stmt2 = null;
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt2 = connection.createStatement();
        String sql;
        String sql2;

        sql = "INSERT INTO M_GROUPS(GROUP_NAME,GROUP_CREATOR_ID,GROUP_TYPE,CREATION_TIME)"
                + " VALUES ('"
                + groupname
                + "','"
                + creator_id
                + "','"
                + grouptype + "',NOW())";

        //stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    rs.next();  
    int key = rs.getInt(1);
    System.out.println(key);

    sql2 = "INSERT INTO M_GROUP_MEMBERS(GROUP_ID,MEMBER_ID,JOIN_TIME)"
            + " VALUES ('"
            + key
            + "','"
            + creator_id
             + "',NOW())";

    stmt2.executeUpdate(sql2);


    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Its give me output like

```
18

java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2812)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
at org.uims.service.GroupService.groupCreation(GroupService.java:106)
at org.uims.servlet.GroupServlet.doPost(GroupServlet.java:66)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I can't see why the second statement would cause an exception such as that above.  Are you sure it's not an error with the first statement in a subsequent call to `groupCreation` that causes the error?  Try printing out the SQL queries before you execute them.  Incidentally, you may wish to consider using PreparedStatements instead of concatenating SQL strings together; what if the group name is `',0,0,NOW()); DROP TABLE M_GROUPS; --`?

Comment: Print out the SQL statements after the variable substitution.  You may find that one of the variable values has a single quote in it.

Comment: First SQL statement seems to be perfect. Because the sysout succeeded with value `18` printed. Error seems to be with the next one.

Comment: @wahid_cse: Which part of the code is line `106`? Is it `stmt2.executeUpdate( sql2 );`

Comment: @Ravinder yes it is stmt2.executeUpdate( sql2 );

Comment: Put `sysout` on `sql2` and post it here. You better use `PreparedStatement` on sql statements.

Comment: I tried this "System.out.println("test before sql2");
     stmt2.executeUpdate(sql2);
  System.out.println("test after sql2");" nothing print give same error

Comment: What was the problem? And, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem in this way....

```
public void groupCreation(String groupname, int grouptype, int creator_id) {

    DatabaseService oDatabaseService = new DatabaseService();
    Connection connection = oDatabaseService.connect();
    Statement stmt = null;
    Statement stmt2 = null;
    Statement stmt3 = null;
    try {
        //Statement stmt = null;            
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String sql;


        sql = "INSERT INTO M_GROUPS(GROUP_NAME,GROUP_CREATOR_ID,GROUP_TYPE,CREATION_TIME)"
                + " VALUES ('"
                + groupname
                + "','"
                + creator_id
                + "','"
                + grouptype + "',NOW())";

       stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
       stmt.close();



    stmt2 = connection.createStatement();
    String sql2;

    sql2 ="select max(group_id)as group_id from m_groups where group_creator_id='"+ creator_id+ "'";

    //System.out.println("before rs for sql2");
    ResultSet rs = stmt2.executeQuery(sql2);
    //System.out.println("after rs for sql2");

    int groupId = 0 ;

    while (rs.next()) {
    groupId =rs.getInt("group_id");
    }

    System.out.println(groupId);

    stmt3 = connection.createStatement();
    String sql3;

     sql3 = "INSERT INTO M_GROUP_MEMBERS(GROUP_ID,MEMBER_ID,JOIN_TIME)"
            + " VALUES ('"
            + groupId
            + "','"
            + creator_id
             + "',NOW())";

    stmt3.executeUpdate(sql3);


    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try{
             if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
          }catch(SQLException se2){
          }// nothing  can do
        try{
             if(stmt2!=null)
                stmt2.close();
          }catch(SQLException se3){
          }// nothing  can do

        try{
             if(stmt3!=null)
                stmt3.close();
          }catch(SQLException se4){
          }// nothing  can do
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```