# set and retrieve auto increment value from mysql to java (set in jlabel)

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Table A have two fields: id, name.

i try to insert values id,name using java mysql  .open form1 and click new jbutton display jlabel1 value = id(autoincrement value) from mysql.and user give (name) input value to jtextfield.and stored asusual.

here my issue:
how can retrieve auto increment value from mysql to java(id set in jlabel).

Comment: voting to close as too broad

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get last inserted auto increment id in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170656/get-last-inserted-auto-increment-id-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

you can fire query to get next value of max id ,example is :-

```
select max(id)+1 from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like below:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO your_table(id,name) VALUES(null, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query, 
    PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ps.setString(1,name_to_insert);

int numRows = ps.executeUpdate();
if(numRows > 0){
   ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
   int generatedID = -1;
   if(rs!=null && rs.next())
        generatedID = rs.getInt(1));
}
```

For more help read Javadoc on PreparedStatement. If this answer satisfies, you click on the "correct mark".(As you are new, you need to know this.)

Comment: i want to set(display)  id value in jlabel before stored.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to show generated ID even before it is generated? If so, how can you ensure what the ID generated by MySQL will be.

Comment: i mean last generated id i want.then i add the value 1 to get next id value.