# Java Spring JDBC last_insert_id()

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I have a web service and a database(MySQL), I made a table called batch which must generate each time I add some value, an unique key.

```
CREATE TABLE batch (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);
```

This is the code for the database table and here you are what I wrote so far:

```
static final String addBatchIdSql = "INSERT INTO batch" + "(description)" + "VALUES (?)";
static final String getBatchIdSql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";

    @Override
        public int getBatchId() {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String batchIDcreation = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            jdbcTemplate.update(addBatchIdSql, batchIDcreation);
            SqlRowSet rowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(getBatchIdSql);
            while (rowSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(rowSet.findColumn("id"));
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

The problem is that each time I try to get the **id** it throws exception which states "invalid column name", I have checked the naming properties in my application in general and could not find any issue, what could be wrong here ://

Comment: You will find [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170656/get-last-inserted-auto-increment-id-in-mysql) very enlightening.

Comment: Useful reference on MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID`: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21181/is-mysqls-last-insert-id-function-guaranteed-to-be-correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try aliasing the column which is returned from your application's call to `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```
static final String getBatchIdSql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id";
```

**Full code:**

```
static final String addBatchIdSql = "INSERT INTO batch" + "(description)" + "VALUES (?)";
static final String getBatchIdSql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id";

@Override
public int getBatchId() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String batchIDcreation = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    jdbcTemplate.update(addBatchIdSql, batchIDcreation);
    SqlRowSet rowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(getBatchIdSql);
    if (rowSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(rowSet.findColumn("id"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, it worked at least I am getting the id but, this method is running on a Scheduler, the problem now I face is that it gives me 1 in each call to this method, can you give me some suggestion please :)

Comment: How exactly are you using the last inserted id?  Off the top of my head, your options would be to either poll, meaning use the value you get at a certain frequency, or take some sort of average over time.

Comment: I am using it to get certain frequency, each time I run this method I need to get the last id :/

Comment: It gives me(prints) in each call 1, instead of for example after 3 times running of this method I am expecting to print 3, because as you understand here I am adding some timestamp and automatically an id, so after each addition of timestamp to the database I want to get the last id generated.

Comment: Does each call to `getBatchId()` take place within a separate transaction?

Comment: Yes, it is in separate transaction

Comment: You should not be seeing this behavior assuming the inserts succeeded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122527/discussion-between-imoteb-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 2):

Try this because, your id as auto increment, so last insert id is your max id

```
 static final String getBatchIdSql = "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM batch";
```

**Total Code:**

```
static final String addBatchIdSql = "INSERT INTO batch" + "(description)" + "VALUES (?)";
 static final String getBatchIdSql = "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM batch";

                @Override
                public int getBatchId() {
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    String batchIDcreation = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                    jdbcTemplate.update(addBatchIdSql, batchIDcreation);
                    SqlRowSet rowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(getBatchIdSql);
                    if (rowSet.next()) {
                        System.out.println(rowSet.findColumn("id"));
                    }
                    return 0;


}
```

Comment: That doesn't necessarily work correctly, eg consider read_committed and concurrent inserts (+ commits) by other transactions.