# How to fetch autoincrement Customer_ID of customer whose data just inserted in above line?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any mysql function for it. To fetch autoincrement Customer_ID of customer whose data(name,contact,address) just inserted in above line of php code? The problem is customer_ID is autoincrement. Is it possible to fetch most recent Customer_ID without select query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get last inserted auto increment id in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170656/get-last-inserted-auto-increment-id-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function. There's plenty of documentation including sample code that you can browse.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know last inserted `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, try this:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

When a new AUTO_INCREMENT value has been generated, you can also obtain it by executing a SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() statement