# Get the latest inserted value for an identity primary key

Tags: java, mysql

I have a `Statement` where I insert some values to a table in my database, this table has a primary key which is identity it's name is : `numBon`.

When I execute the insert command, I want to get the value of `numBon`.

for now I'm working with this code :

```
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(numBon) FROM BonInterne");
int numBon;
if (result.next()) {
            numBon = result.getInt("numBon");
        }
```

Isn't there any other way ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246646/mysql-java-get-id-of-the-last-inserted-value-jdbc?lq=1  I think this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Statement.getGeneratedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) to retrieve autogenerated values.

```
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
st.execute("insert into ... "); //query where the server generates a value for
                                 //an auto incremented column
ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys
int numBon;
if (rs.next()) { 
  numBon = result.getInt(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this an autoincrement column?  Assuming it is, you can do this:

`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`

But that's not database agnostic.  [This article gives a much better answer.](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/autoincrement-with-connectorj.html)  Or you can look at @eidsonator's comment to see a quicker snippet of how to get the ID from the insert statement.