# How to get last inserted ID as Long in java mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I want to get the last inserted ID as `long`. Because the primary key of my table is of `long` data type.

Here's my code:

```
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO testTable(name) VALUES('Anonym')";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            long lastInsertedID = statement.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            System.out.println("LAST INSERTED ID = "+lastInsertedID);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I've tested that when the maximum value of integer reaches I get last 1 as last inserted_id.

By the way, I've gone through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246646/mysql-java-get-id-of-the-last-inserted-value-jdbc).

Thanks.

Comment: `try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) { generatedKeys.next(); SYstem.out.println(generatedKeys.getLong(1)); }` - By [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with the following code snippet:

```
ResultSet rs= statement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) 
{
   System.out.println("Last Inserted ID = "+rs.getLong(1));
}
```

Here's the full code:

```
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO testTable(name) VALUES('Anonym')";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            long lastInsertedID = statement.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ResultSet rs= statement.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (rs.next()) 
            {
              System.out.println("Last Inserted ID = "+rs.getLong(1));
            }    

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```