# How to avoid concurrent read access on a table in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have a table in MySQL that contains a special ID in a particular column. My requirement is to get last inserted ID value (`Select... ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1`), generate a new value based on the acquired ID value and then insert a new record with this generated value.

The problem is that two users will be able to read last inserted ID concurrently and generate two identical IDs.

What I need to do is avoid concurrent read access across the entire table for other threads when one thread is already reading the value.

Is there a way I can achieve this in MySQL without using stored procedures? I've already synchronized the method in my Java application (using spring `JdbcTemplate`) to read/write to db.

Would synchronizing Java method be a good way to implement this behavior or should I use stored procedures to get the behavior?

Comment: One possible way to do this would be to have mysql generate the next key for you - and then retrieve it in your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246646/mysql-java-get-id-of-the-last-inserted-value-jdbc shows you how. Locking the table for concurrent updates will always slow you down

Comment: Is there a case two Program instances calling it via different JDBC connections?

Comment: Java synchronisation is sufficient. I think you haven't implemented synchronisation properly. Please share the Java code also